# How to save State of activity to continue where user left of?

Tags: android, android-activity, save, instance, program-entry-point

How do you save an instance state of an activity. For instance a user opens up a application and clicks a button. A new view is formed and the user types in some information and moves to the next screen in that activity. After that goes back to the main menu of the app. how do you save where the state was before the user went back to the main menu.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Save activity state when starting new activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873263/android-save-activity-state-when-starting-new-activity)

Comment: This has been asked many times. Search for it. In short: Save the state in onPause or onSaveInstanceState. Use SharedPreferences or a Bundle.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

> In addition, the method
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called
>   before placing the activity in such a
>   background state, allowing you to save
>   away any dynamic instance state in
>   your activity into the given Bundle,
>   to be later received in
>   onCreate(Bundle) if the activity needs
>   to be re-created.