# Reloading activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity, reload, back

I am making an android application where i want the activity to reload itself once the back button is pressed on another activities. I have a set of activities. So i got the main one, and a lot of other ones. Let's say the main one is activity-1, and the other ones are activity-2,3,4,5,6,7. Once the user presses a button that takes him to activity-2, or 3, or 4, he will be presented with some buttons again, where one of them will take him to activity-3, or 4, or 5. So when the user is at one activity launched from the main activity, and presses the back button, the main activity should be reloaded, how is this possible? Please help and thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Have all `Activities` except for `Activity-1` call `finish()` immediately after the call to `startActivity(...)`.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea... why do you need to implement this behavior? This goes against android conventions and kind of ruins the user experience in my opinion...

Comment: I have to reload the main activity to reload data from SharedPreferences, as they are changed in the other activities

Answer (score 2):

While starting the Activity call the finish the current Activity for example.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AudioRecordingActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().finish();
```

Then onbackPressed call the new Activity For eg:.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IndexPageActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onBackPressed()` method of your Activity (activity-2, 3, 4 ...) and write code for calling the Main activity in it.

For Example:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, YourMainActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(mainIntent);

    return;
}
```

This will reload your main activity when you press back button from any of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(null);
}
```

Maybe you should try this in main activity

Comment: Gives an exception when starting application, logcat says that it cant pause the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,name of the class where you want to go to);

                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

this code captures the event on back button click and takes you to your desired activity.

Comment: I know, i have used the onKeyDown alot of times before, and i am very familiar with it. But, if i use that code with intents, i will just launch the actity over and over again, wont i???

Comment: That is how an activity is reloaded, you can also [start an activity from its last state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873263/android-save-activity-state-when-starting-new-activity)

Comment: @user1446632 you need to reload the main activity so, what's the problem with above approach?

Comment: When i do so, that application feels a bit weird, and doesn't have the normal animations plus that when i am at the main screen and i am pressing the back button to exit the application, i have to press it alot of times because the same activity is laying on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

use         `finish();` this sends back to the previous activity in your case activity-1 without reloading.

Comment: Just but that's the point, i want to reload the main activity

Comment: then it's very simple Override back button & use "intent" the sameway how you move from one activity to another.