# How to come back to my parent-activity without losing data?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-manifest

I have an `activity` A with a "child activity" which is the `activity` B. 
When I create an activity, like in this case in android, I choose for activity B, that his parent shall be activity A.

So, when I start my application, I have an `icon` in the `appbar` in the activity B, where I can go to the activity A.

In my case, the user for example `edit-text` and manipulate some variables in the activity A and call activity B with Intent.

NOW, in activity B, when I click on the "back" icon, I will go back to the parent activity in this case activity A and all manipulated data are "away", because the screen will be relaunched.

But when I dont click on the icon in the activity B but instead click "back" on my mobile phone, I will come back to activity A and all manipulated data will be still there.

SO my question is, is there a way, to come back to activity A by clicking the back icon in activity B, without that the screen will be relaunched. Because this icon was automatically added, when I say, which activity have to be the parent class. I would like, that I can go back with this icon, but not relaunch the screen, instead continue, where I was "last" time.

I show you a part of my manifest file for the activity B:

```
<activity
            android:name=".strassenfuehrer_screen.VideoPlayerHandlungsleitfadenStrassenfuehrerActivity"
            android:label="Straßenführer  >  Handlungsleitfaden  >  VideoPlayer"
            android:parentActivityName=".strassenfuehrer_screen.MitHandlungsleitfadenStrassenfuehrerScreenActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="de.derdoenerdon.ressourcencockpit.strassenfuehrer_screen.MitHandlungsleitfadenStrassenfuehrerScreenActivity" />
        </activity>
```

Here you can see the "back icon" in the activity B.

[image]

For help, I would be very thankfull, I am new in android and have difficulties with it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873263/android-save-activity-state-when-starting-new-activity

Comment: if you `startActivity` from A, don't finish it, When you back from B, You will get your previous data.

Comment: What do you mean? I mean, when I click on the back icon, it will relaunch my parent again.. or how you mean to start the intent?

Comment: if you switch Activity then don't finish it, when you pressed back, you get whatever you leave behind.

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for a way, to get "this icon", which is clicked and go to the activity which called this activity and use the state, like when you just click "back" of your mobile phone, it shall be also realized, but with this icon, that the activity will be resumed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your manifest for Activity A add this attribute:

> android:launchMode="singleTask"

This should solve your problem.

This makes sure that there is only one instance of Activity A in the BackStack. Therefore Activity A is only created once per Task.

Hope this helps.

for more information https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: Thank you, its very very good. 
It helped me. 
But if Activity A need to go "back" to activity "0" and Then again back to activity A from activity 0, all this "modification" will be lost. Why I can move from B to A without losing modifications? Its good, but it would be perfect, if I can go to 0 and then to A without losing modification

Comment: You have to understand how 'Tasks' and the 'BackStack' in android works. In short, when ever you launch an application a 'Task' is created and each 'Task' has a BackStack. Now when ever an activity is launched it is pushed to the stack and when ever you press the back button(Phones) its popped from the Stack. Any other way you try going back will not take you back but rather start a new instance of the previous activity (That's why you loss the modification, because its a new instance). To avoid multiple instance of an activity to be created within a 'Task' you can do the above.

Comment: This make sure only a single instance of the activity remains in the 'Task' and when ever you call that activity anywhere in your code the same instance is returned(which has the "modifications") so you see your "modifications". To better understand this, visit the link i posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `onSaveInstanceState()` into your `Activity` and save your data before leaving that `Activity`.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("KEY1", Value1);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("KEY2", Value2);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

On coming back to that Activity you can get the saved data as bundle into you `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        int val1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("Key1");
        int val2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("Key2");
    } else {
        // This is the case when you are openning this Activity for the for the first time
    }
}
```

Comment: but do you think, there is a way to find the "selected item" icon and then instead of start new screen, just resume the stopped one?

Comment: @JosipaAllen You can use `SharedPreference` provided by Android.

Comment: No, I mean, when I click on the icon, the screen will be started again and all state I did are away. But, if I implement the behaviour of the selected item, in this case of the icon, if I find out, if the icon was clicked, I just want to "resume" the activity, which called the new activity. This works when I click "back" on my mobile phone, but not when I click on the icon, thats why I ask, maybe that there is a way, to do the same behaviour but with this icon